# Build a 3rd party library from source within an existing Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, zlib, qmake

My project requires a version of `zlib` that isn't present on all target machines, so I want to build `zlib` from source in my project. Then when I `make` my project, it should first build `zlib` so it can be linked to when compiling my project.

One complication is that `zlib` requires `configure` to be run before `make` can be run.

I'm not even sure where to start here. Is there functionality built in to Qt Creator for importing 3rd party library source code like this, or do I need to code out a custom `.pro` file?

I tried the "Add Library..." menu that appears when right-clicking on my project, but it doesn't recognize the library - likely because no `.pro` file exists. I also tried to create a `.pro` file by File -> New Project -> Import Existing Project, and it's able to compile `zlib` once `configure` has been run, but it still doesn't generate a `.pro` file.

I thought that maybe the [subdirs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs) might be useful, but I'm not sure if that is the right route in this situation, and even if it is I am not sure whether I can auto-create the necessary `.pro` file, or I have to create it myself.

Given the source code for a 3rd party library like `zlib`, how do I integrate that into an existing Qt project such that I can compile the library from source, and use it in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following are instructions for adding a 3rd party repository to your Qt project and building it from source.

Some are able to add such libraries via Qt Creator, but I could never get that to work. So these are instructions on how to create the necessary `.pro` and `.pri` files instead. In this post, I will use `zlib` as an example, although other libraries should be similar.

### Setup Build Order

Since your application depends on this library, we need to ensure that the library is built first. To do this, the 3rd party library and the source code for *your application* should be in *sibling* directories.

```
~/myApp $ ls myApp
src zlib
```

You probably already have a `myApp.pro` file that correctly builds your application. I recommend renaming it to `src.pro`, and you'll see why in the next step.

```
mv src/myApp.pro src/src.pro
```

Now you can create a new `myApp.pro` in the root directory.

```
~/myApp $ touch myApp.pro
~/myApp $ ls
myApp.pro src zlib
```

This is a rather simple `.pro` file that merely [says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs) "build `zlib` before `myApp`."

```
# ~/myApp/myApp.pro
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered   # This tells Qt to compile the following SUBDIRS in order
SUBDIRS = zlib src
```

### Create Library .pro File

Now we need to tell Qt how to build our 3rd party library. We do this by creating a new `.pro` file:

```
# ~/myApp/zlib/zlib.pro
TARGET = z            # The name of the output library - can be whatever you want
TEMPLATE = lib        # Tells Qt that we are compiling a library so the output will be bundled into a .a or .so file
CONFIG += staticlib   # Tells Qt that we want a static library, so a .a file. Remove this and you will get a .so file

QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall   # Optional - disable warnings when compiling this library
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall # Optional - disable warnings when compiling this library

HEADERS += \
    crc32.h \
    deflate.h \
    gzguts.h \
    inffast.h \
    inffixed.h \
    inflate.h \
    inftrees.h \
    trees.h \
    zconf.h \
    zlib.h \
    zutil.h

SOURCES += \
    adler32.c \
    compress.c \
    crc32.c \
    deflate.c \
    gzclose.c \
    gzlib.c \
    gzread.c \
    gzwrite.c \
    infback.c \
    inffast.c \
    inflate.c \
    inftrees.c \
    trees.c \
    uncompr.c \
    zutil.c
```

If you are building something other than `zlib`, just change `TARGET` to the name of the library, and replace the contents of `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` with the files that need to be compiled for your library.

You can go ahead now and test out this `.pro` file.

```
~/myApp/zlib/ $ qmake
~/myApp/zlib/ $ make
...
~/myApp/zlib/ $ ls libz.a
libz.a
```

Yay!

### Link The Library Into Your Application

Finally, we need to update the `.pro` file of your application to link in the 3rd party library. There are two parts to this:

1. Add library header files to your include path so the compiler can get the defined symbols from there.
2. Link the static (or shared) library during compile and linking time so the applicable object code can get linked into your application.

*First*, we'll add the header files into the include path. Add this line to `src.pro`.

```
INCLUDEPATH += zlib
```

This allows you to reference `zlib.h` in your code like so:

```
#include "zlib.h"
```

Otherwise, you would have to specify the full relative path of the header like this:

```
#include "zlib/zlib.h"
```

If you're fine with the second method, then there should be no need to update the `INCLUDEPATH` variable.

*Second*, we need to add the arguments the linker needs to find the static (or shared) library itself. Add this line to `src.pro`.

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../zlib -lz
```

The first part (`-L$$PWD/../zlib`) says that the folder containing the library is at `../zlib`, which should be correct since `zlib` is a sibling folder to `src`. The second part (`-lz`) says that the name of the library is `z`. The linker infers from this that the library is actually located in the file `libz.a`.

### Done

At this point, you may have to clean your build by doing a `make distclean`. But from there you should be able to build your project with the 3rd party library included by going to your base directory and running `qmake` and `make`.

```
cd ~/myApp
qmake -r
make
```

<sub>Note: Big thanks go to @LaszloPapp for getting this process started. Much of the source material for this answer came from his answer.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you need to create a project file for it. You can find my version below what I used for several projects.

#### zlib.pro

```
QT       -= core gui

TARGET = zlib
TEMPLATE = lib
# Use this for static zlib rather than the default dynamic
# CONFIG += staticlib
include(zlib.pri)
```

#### zlib.pri

```
HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/crc32.h \
    $$PWD/deflate.h \
    $$PWD/gzguts.h \
    $$PWD/inffast.h \
    $$PWD/inffixed.h \
    $$PWD/inflate.h \
    $$PWD/inftrees.h \
    $$PWD/trees.h \
    $$PWD/zconf.h \
    $$PWD/zlib.h \
    $$PWD/zutil.h

SOURCES += \
    $$PWD/adler32.c \
    $$PWD/compress.c \
    $$PWD/crc32.c \
    $$PWD/deflate.c \
    $$PWD/gzclose.c \
    $$PWD/gzlib.c \
    $$PWD/gzread.c \
    $$PWD/gzwrite.c \
    $$PWD/infback.c \
    $$PWD/inffast.c \
    $$PWD/inflate.c \
    $$PWD/inftrees.c \
    $$PWD/trees.c \
    $$PWD/uncompr.c \
    $$PWD/zutil.c

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
```

Then in the project file including this one, you can do something like this:

#### main.pro

```
# CONFIG += order # If you wanna make sure about order. This is optional.

SUBDIRS += \
    zlib \
    ...
```

If you wanna go even a bit more advanced with qmake, you can do something like this:

```
SUBDIRS += \
    src_zlib \
    src_mylib \
    ...

src_zlib.subdir = $$PWD/zlib
src_zlib.target = sub-zlib
src_zlib.depends =

src_mylib.subdir = $$PWD/mylib
src_mylib.target = sub-mylib
src_mylib.depends = src_zlib
```

As you can see this way, you would have a lot more reasonable control among the dependencies regardless the order set. For instance, you could still keep the entries in alphabetical order which is helpful with proper maintenance in the long run.

Then, you will need a line like this in the project file (.pro) of your subproject, let us say "foo", which depends on zlib.

#### foo.pro

```
LIBS += -L$${PROJECTROOT}/$${SUBDIR_TO_ZLIB} -lz

# These lines are only option, and you do not necessarily need them.
# win32:LIBNAME = zlib.dll
# unix:LIBNAME = libzlib.so
# PRE_TARGETDEPS += $${PROJECTROOT}/$${BUILD_SUBDIR_LIBS}/$${LIBNAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you are using QT Creator you could try to investigate "Project Settings" -> "Add Build Step" -> "Custom build step" and add script file there. 
This could help to build lib before and then you just need to link it to your project.

I'm not sure, but most likelly you could pass the compilers settings like an argument to this script. I'm triing to solve it right now.